# Fragment call a method from anoter fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have 3 classes: 2 fragments and one activity with pager adapter. I want to call the method from fragment A which creates buttons programmatically from fragment B. Those buttons should be created in layout tied to fragment A (fragment B has its own layout).  How do i do it?

All the solutions with transactions/replacing are not working, maybe im not using them right dunno.
Im not sure what code do i need to add, so heres my activity:

```
public class All extends FragmentActivity {

ViewPager pager;
PagerAdapter pagerAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    pagerAdapter = new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    pager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(pager);
}

private class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    static final int NUM_ITEMS = 2;

    public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int pos) {

        if (pos==0)
        {
            return Scroll.newInstance();
         }
        else
            return Fav.newInstance();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return NUM_ITEMS;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int pos) {
        if (pos==0)
            return "1";
        else
            return "2";
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Can you please add the related code as a [mcve]?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to first review the official Google tutorial:
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

here you can understand the basic pattern of fragment to fragment communication.